# How best to create a resource-only package in nix?

Tags: nix

For integration testing, I have to fetch some resources. My thinking is that it might work well to have an integration test data package. What I'm doing right now looks roughly like this:

```
pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
  resource = [ (fetchResource { url = ...; sha256 = ...; }) ... ];
}
```

where `fetchResources` is just cutting down on boilerplate to use `fetchzip`.

Does nix have an appropriate way of packaging these kind of nonexecutable resources that would usually go in `/usr/share` ? Eg how `bin`, `lib`, `Applications`, or `include`(?) seem to each have hardcoded meanings that set things up properly in environment paths, etc.

It seems a bit overkill to end up referencing a different nix store path for each and every item downloaded - it seems like it would make more sense to generate one package with all the data. However, then I need a way to reference it from other packages, and I'd like to conform to existing conventions if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A store path per item downloaded does have the benefit of deduplicating the data when copying closures with e.g. a binary cache. So if it makes sense for your data you could write a derivation that references the individual unpacked resources by symlink.
The number of store paths only becomes a consideration if your data items are really tiny or if you want to use them in `dockerTools.buildLayeredImage` where store paths have a more significant cost (as of 2020).

Derivations exist in roughly two flavors. One uses the FHS inside its store path, allowing its contents to be discoverable when used with `buildInputs`, `nix-env -i`, `environment.systemPackages`, etc.
Alternatively, a derivation can put its data directly at the root of its output path, which is simple and convenient when you're only referencing the path in a script.

The choice depends on whether your integration test expects the data in an FHS location that makes it discoverable. Discovery usually works via some `PATH`- like environment variable, but you could also make it discoverable by using e.g. `symlinkJoin` to "overlay" the test and data so that relative paths work.

I'd generally recommend against such autodiscovery mechanisms in new applications, unless there's a reason, like compatibility with non-Nix installations.
To make it easy to understand, you can hardly beat the simplicity of for example

```
checkPhase = "${testRunner}/bin/run-tests ${testData}";
```